# Express/Mongoose update document when clicking at it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I load my data from mongodb atlas and each document gets a delete and edit button.

The delete button already works!

I'm using handlbars for displaying the content:

```
<section class="get">
    <h3>CONTENT</h3>
    <div>
        {{# each items }}
            <article class="item">
                <div>ID: {{ this._id }}</div>
                <div>Name: {{ this.name }}</div>
                <div>Description: {{ this.description }}</div>
                <div>Price: {{ this.price }}</div>
                <img src="data:image/png;base64, {{this.image}}" alt="{{ this.name }}">
                <button class="edit-button">EDIT</button>
                <button class="delete-button" onclick="openDeleteForm.call(this)">DELETE</button>
            </article>
        {{/each}}
        <button class="open-button" onclick="openForm()">ADD</button>
    </div>
</section>
```

Now my question is how can I do editing - I want to open a Popup where I have an input field for every field with the value from the item clicked at. Should i get the values from HTML or somehow with the handlebars `{{ this.value }}`?
Or maybe there is a better solution than one of the ones I mentioned.

This is my "Add item - Popup" and I want the "Edit item - Popup" to be the same but with prefilled values.

[image: Add Popup]

---

Edit: API:
insert method:

```
router.post("/insert", upload.single("image"), (req, res) => {


    const buffer = new Buffer(fs.readFileSync(req.file.path)).toString("base64");

    var item = {
        name: req.body.name,
        description: req.body.description,
        price: req.body.price,
        image: buffer
    };


    var data = new MenuData(item);


    data.save((err) => {
        res.redirect('/admin');
    });


});
```

delete:

```
router.post('/delete', function (req, res, next) {
    let id = req.body.deleteId;

    MenuData.findByIdAndRemove(id).exec((err) => {
        res.redirect('/admin');
    });
});
```

---

Another question: How can i reduce loading time of the images (as you can see I store images as base64 in mongodb atlas). Just resize them (does resizing makes the base64 shorter)?

Comment: Which part is interact with mongodb ? did you using api or just using server rendering

Comment: I think api (index.js file where get and post is handled with node/express)

Comment: So then please add more code relate to api

Comment: @HellCatVN edited